# Can't rewrite from main domain to subfolder using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, migration, subdirectory

For one of my clients I have to migrate their current domain to a subdirectory.
They have some software online that will also be migrated.

Apart from this, the company has USBs with software on them that connect with a platform on the website which needs to be migrated.

My initial idea was to redirect the URLs used in the USBs using .htaccess

After trying to understand .htaccess I've tried numerous different approaches to redirect the url.
I've searched multiple websites to try and get this to work
At this moment I don't have any solution at hand, so I figured I would ask on StackOverflow, hoping I can get closer to a solution.

The website, 'https://example.com/' , used to just be an online platform.
We've moved all files from example.com/ to example.com/online/

On example.com/ we now have a Wordpress website running, I can get to all pages within wordpress without issues.

I can get to example.com/online/ just fine using buttons on the wordpress site (or just typing in the browser).
But if someone uses their USB to try and connect to a certain page, for example: login/create.php it will get sent to https://example.com/login/create.php where I would like it to be sent to https://example.com/online/login/create.php .

Is it possible to redirect to /online/login/ everytime someone goes to /login/ for example?
How would I go about doing this?

What I've tried:

Somewhere (I believe) on StackOverflow I found a similar post.
The solution was this htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/login%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ online/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

I've tried using [this](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/) tool to test my htaccess code, and according to that site it should work.
It redirects from example.com/login/something.php to example.com/online/login/something.php .
But it doesn't work on the actual domain.

From my message you've probably noticed I'm no expert in htaccess, and would appreciate some guidance, if possible.

Kind regards,
ChefStoney

**EDIT:** I will keep trying things that seem likely to work.
On the above mentioned tool I tried the following htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/online/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /online/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ online/index.php [L]
```

This code redirects from example.com/login/whatever.php to example.com/online/login/whatever.php while using the tool.

When trying it on the domain itself, nothing happens.
What am I missing?